# How can I get my setters to set?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, setter

I'm trying to do lazy instantiation for my `arrayWithCurrentLadder` property so that my array gets allocated and initiated at least once. However, it seems that my setter never actually gets called, because when I try to do stuff with the objects in the array nothing happens, and so I decided to try and `NSLog` an object in the array to find out if I was getting an actual value (I put stars by that line of code so you can see) and the debugger said `(null)`, so I'm assuming my setter isn't actually setting. I added random `NSLog`s in my setter to see again but the messages didn't even show up in the debugger. Why won't my setter set?

```
#import "LViewController.h"

@interface LViewController ()
    @property (nonatomic) BOOL firstLadder; 
    @property (nonatomic, weak) NSMutableArray *arrayWithCurrentLadder;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *playingView;//connects playingView to LViewController
@end

@implementation LViewController

    @synthesize playingView = _playingView;
    @synthesize firstLadder = _firstLadder;
    @synthesize arrayWithCurrentLadder = _arrayWithCurrentLadder;

    -(void)setArrayWithCurrentLadder:(NSMutableArray *)arrayWithCurrentLadder {
        if(!_arrayWithCurrentLadder)
            _arrayWithCurrentLadder = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10];

        NSLog(@"kgjfkjg");

        _arrayWithCurrentLadder = arrayWithCurrentLadder;

        NSLog(@"dkfjdk");

    }

    - (IBAction)buildLadder:(UIButton *)sender {
        if (self.firstLadder) {

        *******************************************************************************************
            NSLog(@"%@", [[self.arrayWithCurrentLadder lastObject] frame].origin.x);
        *******************************************************************************************    

            if (sender.frame.origin.x == [[self.arrayWithCurrentLadder lastObject] frame].origin.x) {
                sender.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
                [self.arrayWithCurrentLadder addObject:sender];
            }   
        }

    }

    - (IBAction)startingLadder:(UIButton *)sender {
        if (!self.firstLadder) {
            [self.arrayWithCurrentLadder addObject:sender];
        }

        sender.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        self.firstLadder = YES;
    }

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should override the getter instead of the setter:

```
- (NSMutableArray *)arrayWithCurrentLadder
{
    if (nil == _arrayWithCurrentLadder) {
        _arrayWithCurrentLadder = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10] retain];
    }

    return _arrayWithCurrentLadder;
}
```

Comment: That will neither fix the problem, nor address a few other issues with the code... and it is generally a bad idea to lazy initialize in a getter as that'll screw with KVO or anything else that expects a "get" to not change state.

Comment: If necessary, the kvo calls can be added.

Comment: @bbum:could you expand a bit? Apple often demonstrates use of lazy init in getters -- eg. in the app delegate Core Data stack in Xcode's default templates. Arguably it's semantically a bit misleading, but OTOH it's a nice way to reduce the error-proneness of statement-order in init code.

Answer (score 0):

Your setter is likely setting just fine, but your `@property` declaration means that the object isn't preserved.

Assuming ARC, that declaration of a `weak` `@property` isn't going to do what you want;   unless you have something else strongly referencing the object, the ARC runtime will quite happily release it upon exit from that method.

Note also that the following is pointless;  that if() test and assignment is effectively a no-op (and would be a leak under manual retain-release).

```
if (!foo) foo = [[... alloc] init];
foo = somethingElse;
```